# How do I use multiple functions inside resize function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I want to use multiple functions inside windows.width resize function. This is some of the code I have tried.. How can I use this code only in tablet mobile and not in laptop and pc website view

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(this).width() < 1000) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a.searchkey').click(function() {
                $('.search').slideToggle('fast');
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            });
        });
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
                $('.search').hide('fast');
            }
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
                    $('.bottom_menu').hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).scrollTop() > 10
                    $('.bottom_menu').show('fast');
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The width is width dependent, it makes no different what device you are on, please clarify if you are trying to target specific devices or target by width

Comment: Your question's title, and question's description are very incoherent

Comment: `if (jQuery.browser.mobile){...}` is probably what your looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use this minified jQuery snippet to detect if your user is viewing using a mobile device. If you need to test for a specific device I’ve included a collection of JavaScript snippets below which can be used to detect various mobile handheld devices such as iPad, iPhone, iPod, iDevice, Andriod, Blackberry, WebOs and Windows Phone.
[**How to Detect Mobile Devices using jQuery**](http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var handler1 = function() {
       alert( "handler1" );
    };
    var handler2 = function() {
      alert( "handler2" );
    };
    var handler3 = function() {
       alert( "handler3" );
    };
    if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
    {
        console.log('You are using a mobile device!');
        $( window ).bind( "resize.handler1", handler1 );
        $( window ).bind( "resize.handler2", handler2 );
        $(window ).bind( "resize.handler3", handler3 );       
    }
    else
    {
       console.log('You are not using a mobile device!');
    }

    $("input").click(function(){
         $( window ).unbind("resize."+$(this).attr("id") );
    });
});
```

`jQuery.browser.mobile` is a library that mentioned above
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rsrdvp2h/)